# Post new domain to Google Calendar Resources using API and Postman

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, postman

I am new on APIs. I created a resource conference room for my environment and it is accessible for people who is under my g-suite domain. But the problem is these conference rooms are common areas and people who work under other domains also want to access them. So I am trying to give access to their domains. I found an article about it: https://support.robinpowered.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001164606-Allow-outside-G-Suite-domains-to-book-your-resource-calendars

I followed these steps. But problem is, when i do GET request via postman i manage to get json result showing resource details such as who has access(which is only my domain at the moment). But when I want to post new domain there, it returns 404 all the time. I upload the relevant screenshots below.
Note: domain testmain.com is not a real domain. I put it there as sample and show how i write domain there.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update teh ACL rules you need to go though the ACL methods [Acl overview](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl)

You should be using [acl.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert)

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/acl

{
  "kind": "calendar#aclRule",
  "id": string,
  "scope": {
    "type": string,
    "value": string
  },
  "role": string
}
```

You are using a GET you should be using a POST

[image]

Comment: I am using postman to do this operation. I am not sure postman lets to use methods. Any chance that you check the article on my first post? Maybe you can tell me why i get 404. Because i see no problem

Comment: I am sure that postman will let you do this.  The first line Post you change yours from a get to a post.   then you add the url where the post goes to.   Then you add the json in the body.  I do this all the time works like a charm.   You get a 404 becouse you are sending a get request instead of a post you are also connecting to the wrong endpoint to be able to update /insert  the files you are trying to

Comment: Only first image contains GET request. I put it as sample to prove same access token and url works on get request but it throws 404 on POST request. Please check rest of the screenshots You will see that they are POST requests. @DalmTo

Comment: 404 means the page does not exist so i would check the spelling of your url and what ever you have in the variable.

Comment: If page does not exist how do i get successful response when i use get request? But 404 on post request?

Comment: This is common REST API behavior. It's not saying that the Uri doesn't exist, but that something else isn't correct - maybe you're missing identifying information in your POST body, maybe you're supplying invalid identifiers, maybe the GET and POST endpoints aren't the same. Review the API's documentation to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @Josh if it was an authorization issue it would be a different error message i think. 404 Not Found means not found.  I think you should try runing the request though [Google apis explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.acl.insert)  I still think something is wrong with the url you are calling.